# Why aren't terminals started by VS Code remote explorer login shells?

Tags: linux, visual-studio-code, rhel8

I added a custom .sh script to /etc/profile.d in order to set some additional environment variables that I would like to be set for all users starting bash login shells.  I also added an echo temporarily to the /etc/profile script to confirm what is being executed and the output looks like this when I ssh to the RHEL8 VM.

```
Last login: Fri Jun  2 10:57:18 2023 from 10.93.12.165
source /etc/profile.d/PackageKit.sh
source /etc/profile.d/colorgrep.sh
source /etc/profile.d/colorls.sh
source /etc/profile.d/colorsysstat.sh
source /etc/profile.d/colorxzgrep.sh
source /etc/profile.d/colorzgrep.sh
source /etc/profile.d/flatpak.sh
source /etc/profile.d/gawk.sh
source /etc/profile.d/k3s.sh
source /etc/profile.d/lang.sh
source /etc/profile.d/less.sh
source /etc/profile.d/modules.sh
source /etc/profile.d/scl-init.sh
source /etc/profile.d/ssh-x-forwarding.sh
Could not find ':' in DISPLAY: needs-to-be-defined
source /etc/profile.d/toolbox.sh
source /etc/profile.d/vim.sh
source /etc/profile.d/vte.sh
source /etc/profile.d/which2.sh
source /etc/profile.d/sh.local
[sfox@gxp2-lnx8 ~]>echo $KUBECONFIG
/etc/rancher/k3s/k3s.yaml
```

The above confirms what I expect that /etc/profile is sourced.  Now when I connect to the same VM via the VS Code remote explorer and I echo the environment I can clearly see that the /etc/profile is not being sourced.  Why?  This seems like a major problem.  There is a lot of code and variable set within a typical /etc/profile so this seems like deficiency unless I am misunderstanding.

If I then run "bash -l" then I can see that /etc/profile is sourced which also confirms that the initial terminal and those launched from the terminal menu are not login terminals.